# put each text surrounded via html tag, into an array?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

using nokogiri,

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(your_html)
doc.xpath("//text()").to_s
```

this does the job, however, it puts everything into one flat text.

i need to take each text surrounded via html tags

```
<b> text</b>
<h1>text3</b>
```

and put them into array. ["text", "text3"]

what is the recommended action ?

i thought of doing

doc.xpath("*").text

but dont know how to iterate through it all.

Comment: You'd better kept on the same old question and added a comment to it.

Comment: yeh, i know but it would not recognize me as the original asker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(your_html)
doc.xpath("//text()").to_a
```

Comment: wow this works really well! it even handles things that are just separated by <br> tags